# Gratuity Payment Cheque Dishonored (Account frozen - demonetization drive) - Should I hand it back before i get another one?

Tags: india, check, legal, benefits

So, I moved out of this organization (will not reveal the name yet) a month and half ago. I got the gratuity payment cheque within three weeks. I held on to it for another two weeks and then deposited it. Surprisingly the cheque was dishonored!

Surprising because: It is a well known MNC (Fortune 500) and would not do something like that.

The reason was (as they say) all corporate current accounts are frozen (following a notice from RBI) at the moment because of the demonetization drive going on in India. The account will be active after re-verification (they said).

They are asking me to return the cheque before they can issue a new one. Should I return it? 
Or should I ask them to issue a new one while I hold on to this one. (May be asking them to request a stop payment for the dishonored check - for their peace of mind)
Or should i be doing something else? (I am no expert in banking stuff. Need some guidance)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> They are asking me to return the cheque before they can issue a new one. Should I return it? Or should I ask them to issue a new one while I hold on to this one.

You can return it. Just for safety, make sure that you get an acknowledgment from them that they have received back the cheque. Best done in person, rather than sending it over by post.

> May be asking them to request a stop payment for the dishonored check
>   - for their peace of mind

You could, however large Organizations are slightly process oriented and they will not do anything that is out of processes.

> Or should i be doing something else?

Do read too much into this, if its a large Organization, very less will go wrong. Just ensure that all the communications are via email and avoid any verbal discussions.

Comment: Emphasis on the "via email" part. Get everything in writing!